# How to add a new page to the bottom of a Pages document with AppleScript

Tags: applescript, iwork

I've been experimenting with the Pages object model and am trying to manipulate it with AppleScript. I'm able to use this command to add new pages to the document.
                    make new page
The problem I'm facing is that it always creates the new page at the beginning of the document instead of at the end of the document.

The dictionary says that the entire syntax is

```
set theResult to make new type class ¬
 at location specifier ¬
 with data anything ¬
 with properties record
```

and I've tried to use BOTTOM and END as values for location specifier, and they've been unsuccessful. What am I missing, please, to create a new page or a new section at the bottom of the document?

Answer (score 0):

Just think in *natural language*.

You want to `make` a `new page at the end of` the `sections` in the `front document`

```
tell application "Pages"
    tell front document
        set newPage to make new page at the end of sections
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: I'm using the code but still adding pages to the start and not to the end in the loop. The first time through the loop, the new page is added at the bottom. The next time through, it's added between pages 1 and 2. Is it because the insertion point is still on page 1? The code wants to keep adding page 2s.

Comment: In fact, I've discovered that if I manually run the code and put a breakpoint before the Make New Page command, and if I manually select the last page (on the thumbnails view) before the Make new Page command, then everything works. But I don't understand why. And I also haven't been able to use AppleScript to select that last page.

Comment: Pages seems to be special. You have to add the pages at the end of the **sections**. As far as I know you cannot select pages in Pages.

Comment: What do I have wrong? - it still seems to be adding pages before. I'm using.  tell application "Pages"     
repeat with i from 1 to 4     
tell front document         
set newPage to make new page at the end of sections      
set body text of newPage to I      
end tell                
end repeat           
end tell

Comment: I agree that there appears to be a limitation setting CurrentPage of the document. I've tried Set current page to page 2 of pages of myDocument and I get an error. (I'm using myDocument instead of front document so I can see its properties. It seems that if we can find a way to select the last page, then this will all work -- instead of the first page being permanently selected. What is the code to move the insertion point?

Comment: It seems that the problem comes from trying to access one of the pages in myDocument. I also get an error when executing the line `display dialog of body text of page 2 of pages of myDocument` -- _Pages got an error: Can’t make body text of page 2 of every page of document id "BD910B92-0AEF-4CE3-82A0-689C4B887E42" into type string._